# How to set distance between material-ui slider marks

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a material-ui slider that I have done some custom CSS work to. It is sitting in a div with a small width so overflowX is needed. How do I keep a margin between the marks? I need about a 5px margin between each mark.

[link to demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2qxhy?file=/demo.tsx)

[image: slider]

This is what I want it to look like.
[image: desired result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's no way to add a specific 5px margin to each mark, I might be wrong, but what I found out is that the spacing of the marks is being defined by their CSS `position` attribute set to `absolute` and the CSS `left` attribute that is being assigned as an inline style on render according to the following calculation that you can find on '\node_modules@material-ui\core\Slider\Slider.js' line 96:

```
function valueToPercent(value, min, max) {
 return (value - min) * 100 / (max - min);
}
```

this is then being applied to the span on line 885/6:

```
var percent = valueToPercent(mark.value, min, max);
var style = axisProps[axis].offset(percent);
```

So I believe In order to render that number of items with that width and more spacing you need to increase the width of your slider which in your demo I did by increasing the width of the sliderDivStyle on line 97/98 from:

```
  width: "100%",
  overflow: "hidden",
```

to:

```
  width: "400%",
  // overflow: "hidden",
```

Here is a link to the demo with the result:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-lb3rc?file=/demo.tsx